# Login a website from another webpage with PHP

Tags: php, post, curl, authentication, get

So i have a  website http://example.com
And there is a website i would like to login; http://target.com
I want a script that can fill the login form (username and password) at http://target.com FROM my site.

so when a user click on http://example.com/login.php&username=John&password=12345

He should log in http://target.com directly AND sent to the welcome page.

I got this code;

```
$url = "http://target.com";
$post = "username=John&password=12345&login=++Ba%F0lan++";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
echo curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

BUT it's not forwarding me to the welcome page. instead it shows me an error on http://example.com (page not found)

ALSO it's not getting username and password data from url. but i think i will solve it on my own later.

Any help?

Comment: For me it's look like phishing script.

Answer (score 3):

OK... This is fundamentally much harder than you think, if not impossible if `target.com` does not explicitly support some kind of login-by-proxy. You have three parties here:

```
client   ---->   example.com   ---->   target.com
```

Typically the client logs in at `target.com` and ***receives a session cookie***, which is his login token. Only `target.com` can set a cookie for `target.com`.

When you proxy this process and let `example.com` login at `target.com`, then `example.com` receives the cookie. That's fine, now `example.com` is authenticated. But it cannot pass this authentication on to the client, because `example.com` cannot set a cookie on behalf of `target.com`. `example.com` could pass on the received cookie to the client, but that cookie would only be valid for `example.com`.

Unless `target.com` supports some sort of URL-based login scheme which does not depend on cookies, you're fundamentally screwed.

Comment: @Peter (Whose comment used to be here) Sure, so `example.com` just prepares the login form with pre-filled values and can cause the client to automatically submit it through Javascript. That can work, but it may also fail if `target.com` employs sensible CSRF protection.